# SQL Server - LIKE [XXXX]

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to return only values which contain the text [XXXX] in a specific field.
My query is returning values which have 4 digit numbers, as I assume SQL server is treating [XXXX] as any number with 4 digits.

I have a test query below with values list to demonstrate the problem.

```
select X.VadDesc 
From (VALUES
('Product AAAA Description'), 
('Product BBBB Description'), 
('Product [XXXX] Description'), 
('Product2 [XXXX] Description'), 
('Product 2 [AAAA] Description'), 
('Product X 1234 Description'),
('Product X 1235 Description'),
('Product X 1236 Description'),
('Product X 1237 Description')
) as X (VadDesc)
Where X.VadDesc like '%[XXXX]%'
```

My query should only return:

```
Product [XXXX] Description
Product2 [XXXX] Description
```

But it returns:

```
Product [XXXX] Description
Product2 [XXXX] Description
Product X 1234 Description
Product X 1235 Description
Product X 1236 Description
Product X 1237 Description
```

How can I do this?
I don't just want to look for XXXX as this this may be in rows I don't want to return.

Comment: `[ABC]` is a character range. It means that the pattern should match against any of the characters A,B,C. You need to escape [ and ]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select X.VadDesc 
From (VALUES
('Product AAAA Description'),  
('Product BBBB Description'),  
('Product [XXXX] Description'),  
('Product2 [XXXX] Description'),  
('Product 2 [AAAA] Description'),  
('Product X 1234 Description'),  
('Product X 1235 Description'),  
('Product X 1236 Description'),  
('Product X 1237 Description')  
) as X (VadDesc) 
Where X.VadDesc like '%[[]XXXX]%'
```

Comment: One thing to note that this condition will also get products like 'Product [XX[]XXX] Description'

Comment: The correct way is `[[]XXXX]` . All credits to [@MartinSmith](http://stackoverflow.com/users/73226/martin-smith)

Comment: Yes Correct. I was serching for it. Added in Answer. Thanks @ughai .

Answer (score 5):

Use an [Escape character](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms710128%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to escape `[` like this `'%\[XXXX\]%' {escape '\'}`.

**Query**

```
select X.VadDesc 
From (VALUES
('Product AAAA Description'), 
('Product BBBB Description'), 
('Product [XXXX] Description'), 
('Product2 [XXXX] Description'), 
('Product 2 [AAAA] Description'), 
('Product X 1234 Description'),
('Product X 1235 Description'),
('Product X 1236 Description'),
('Product X 1237 Description')
) as X (VadDesc)
Where X.VadDesc like '%\[XXXX\]%' {escape '\'}
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c0317/4)

Comment: don't bother asking, some people just like to downvote random answers, better to just let it go

Comment: Whoever downvoted probably doesn't know that you can specify your own escape character in `LIKE`. The other correct answer also got a downvote

Comment: @Lamak - I prefer to ask so that if there is a valid reason, I can improve my answer and learn something new in the process. Looks like this isn't one of those cases.

Comment: I would like to know what's the purpose of `{ }` in SQL? I've always used `WHERE X.VadDesc LIKE '%\[XXXX\]%' ESCAPE '\'` and it worked just fine.

Comment: @EvaldasBuinauskas - It's optional :)